# Without "\global", we can still change "\count0"?

Tags: tex-core, grouping

As on page 21 of the book **The TeXbook**, if we need to change the page number to add 1, we need to use `\global\advance\count0 by 1`, as `\advance\count0 by 1` couldn't change `\count0` in other groups. However,

```
hello
\advance\count0 by 1
\bye % end the document
```

[image]

can still change page number to be +1, which is 2 now. So, how should I understand the `\global` here, as whether there is `\global`, the page number is always 2. In what condition, without `\global`, we can't change the page number?

This question is about another one, on page 21 of that book, the exercise 5.6 says:

> If you think you understand local and global definitions, here’s a little test to make sure: Suppose \c stands for ‘\count1=’, \g stands for ‘\global\count1=’, and \s stands for ‘\showthe\count1’. What values will be shown?

`{\c1\s\g2{\s\c3\s\g4\s\c5\s}\s\c6\s}\s`

The result is `{1 {2 3 4 5}4 6} 4`. Why?

---

```
\def\c{\count1=}
\def\g{\global\count1=}
\def\s{\showthe\count1}
{\c1\s\g2{\s\c3\s\g4\s\c5\s}\s\c6\s}\s


\bye% end the document
```

Why isn't this code right?

Comment: You are at the top level ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first part of this question, you're changing the value of `\count0` at the top level (you're not inside of any group -- or if you prefer to think of it that way, you're at group level 0), so in effect this has the same result as if you'd done `\global`, since there is no wider scope, hence your page number is indeed changed.

In the second part of the question, I hope the following helps understandig it:

```
{% start of group level 1
    \c1 % local value 1
    \s  % shows 1
    \g2 % local and global value 2
    {% start of group level 2
        \s  % shows 2
        \c3 % local value 3
        \s  % shows 3
        \g4 % local and global value 4
        \s  % shows 4
        \c5 % local value 5
        \s  % shows 5
    }% end of group level 2, restores to last active value valid above level 2 -> global 4
    \s  % shows 4
    \c6 % local value 6
    \s  % shows 6
}% end of group level 1, restores to last active value valid above level 1 -> global 4
\s % shows 4
```

With `global` meaning it changes the value at this group-level and every higher group-level, so `global` in `group level 2` changes the value in that group, and `group level 1`, and `group level 0`, hence globally.

Comment: May you help check my updated queation? I want to test it. Thanks.

Comment: @Y.zeng please refrain from editing your question invalidating answers given to you. Instead ask a new question if you got a new question. In this case however, there is no new question, your code does what it should be doing, it just doesn't print the result in the document, `\showthe` shows the current value of the counter on the terminal and in the log, not in the resulting DVI/PDF/whatever output format, and there the correct values are displayed (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 6, 4).

Comment: Change `\showthe` to `\the`, and the result is `2432432`. If not change, the log file is empty and the content in terminal is `> 1.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
\g ->\global 
             \count 1=
l.4 {\c1\s\g
            2{\s\c3\s\g4\s\c5\s}\s\c6\s}\s
? `

Comment: @Y.zeng if you change `\showthe` to `\the` the thing becomes expandable, and `\c6\s` becomes `\count1=6\the\count1` with `\count1` having the value 4 it becomes `\count1=64` (for instance). Instead do `\def\s{\relax\the\count1 }` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Why `\the` will make it expandable and why need `\relax` here and what is the function of `\relax`?

Comment: @Y.zeng `\relax` stops the number scanning from any previous `\c`-usage. You can read about `\relax` in the TeXbook, it's an unexpandable primitive which does nothing, but stops TeX from scanning ahead for several things (e.g., numerals while reading a number, or `plus` and `minus` in glue expressions). And `\the` makes it expandable because it's an expandable primitive (again, documented in the TeXbook).

Answer (score 4):

Typically, the value of `\count0` (aliased to `\pageno` in plain TeX) is modified inside the output routine, whose commands are executed inside a group. Therefore the plain output routine has `\advancepageno` which in turn is

```
\def\advancepageno{\ifnum\pageno<\z@ \global\advance\pageno\m@ne
  \else\global\advance\pageno\@ne \fi} % increase |pageno|
```

as the convention of plain TeX is that negative values of `\count0` will result in Roman numerals to be printed as page numbers. Indeed, the page number is printed by `\folio`:

```
\def\folio{\ifnum\pageno<\z@ \romannumeral-\pageno \else\number\pageno \fi}
```

Complete quotation:

> Output routines are always protected by enclosing them
> in groups, so that they do not inadvertently mess up the rest of TeX; but
> the change to `\count0` would disappear if it were kept local to the
> output group. The command
>
> ```
>  \global\advance\count0 by 1
> ```
>
> solves the problem; it increases `\count0` and makes this value stick around
> at the end of the output routine. In general, `\global` makes the immediately
> following definition pertain to all existing groups, not just to the
> innermost one.

This is a *specific* feature of `\count0` and you shouldn't “export” it to other counters. Of course, if you change `\count0` at the top level, you don't need `\global`.

When you do `\showthe\count1`, you're presented the current value of the counter:

```
{% open a group
\count1=1
\showthe\count1 % << 1
\global\count1=2
{
\showthe\count1 % << 2
\count1=3
\showthe\count1 % << 3
\global\count1=4
\showthe\count1 % << 4
\count1=5
\showthe\count1 % << 5
}
\showthe\count1 % << 4
\count1=6
\showthe\count1 % << 6
}
\showthe\count1 % << 4
```

You may want to better see what's going on by running `pdftex` that has `\tracingassigns` on

```
\tracingrestores=1 
\tracingassigns=1
{% group level 1
\count1=1
\immediate\write20{\the\count1} % << 1
\global\count1=2
{% group level 2
\immediate\write20{\the\count1} % << 2
\count1=3
\immediate\write20{\the\count1} % << 3
\global\count1=4
\immediate\write20{\the\count1} % << 4
\count1=5
\immediate\write20{\the\count1} % << 5
}% group level 1
\immediate\write20{\the\count1} % << 4
\count1=6
\immediate\write20{\the\count1} % << 6
}% group level 0
\immediate\write20{\the\count1} % << 4

\end
```

The log file will be

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdftex 2023.9.21)  8 NOV 2023 09:17
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**counters
(./counters.tex{into \tracingassigns=1}
{changing \count1=0}
{into \count1=1}

1
{globally changing \count1=1}
{into \count1=2}
2
{changing \count1=2}
{into \count1=3}
3
{globally changing \count1=3}
{into \count1=4}
4
{changing \count1=4}
{into \count1=5}
5
{restoring \count1=4}
{retaining \count1=4}
4
{changing \count1=4}
{into \count1=6}
6
{restoring \count1=4}
{retaining \count1=4}
4
 )
No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

and the console will print

```
1
2
3
4
5
4
6
4
```

as predicted in the comments to the commands.

Comment: +1 Great answer! Is the old TeX Book still relevant with all the new activity of the LaTeX team?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Of course it is!